# getAdapterPosition() throws an Exception [android]

Tags: java, android, exception, android-recyclerview

I have tried my best to understand the issue around this single problem. I am creating a function which involves editing contents(Items) of a `recyclerview`. It works just fine when editing one row but throws an `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds` exception when editing another row in the `recyclerview`.

This code is the source of the error.

```
((ClassListOnSetup) context).editClassnameAt(classes.get(getAdapterPosition()).getId(), getAdapterPosition(), classesBean);
```

I think the `getAdapterPosition()` method could be throwing this error:

Here is the `editClassnameAt()` method for more reference purposes:

```
public void editClassnameAt(long id,int position, String classname ){
    demeaSQL.updateAclass(id,classname);

    classListOnSetupRecyclerAdapter.notifyItemChanged(position);
    classListOnSetupRecyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    displayClassList();
}
```

Error message at **LogCat**

> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=10; index=-1
>   at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:413) at
>   com.example.demeainc.demea.ClassListOnSetupRecyclerAdapter$ClassListOnSetupViewHolder$2$2.onClick(ClassListOnSetupRecyclerAdapter.java:87)
>   at
>   android.support.v7.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:162)

What am I getting wrong. Any help please?

For those of you that will like to review the full code,
Here is my Adapter class full code:

```
public class ClassListOnSetupRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ClassListOnSetupRecyclerAdapter.ClassListOnSetupViewHolder {

    //simple list of classes(mDataSet for Adapter)
    private List<ClassesBean> listClasses;
    private Context mContext;

    public class ClassListOnSetupViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public TextView textView_classname;
        public Button delete_button_classsetup;

        public ClassListOnSetupViewHolder(final Context context, View itemView, final List<ClassesBean> classes) {
            super(itemView);

            textView_classname = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView_classname);
            delete_button_classsetup = itemView.findViewById(R.id.delete_button_classsetup);

            delete_button_classsetup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                    //  if(view.equals(delete_button_classsetup)) {
                        Log.i("Deletes", "Button pressed");
                        long id = classes.get(getAdapterPosition()).getId();

                        ((ClassListOnSetup) context).removeAt(getAdapterPosition(), classes.get(getAdapterPosition()).getId());
                        Toast.makeText(context, "You Clicked ID = " + id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

                    View promptView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.edit_class, null);

                    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogueBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);

                    alertDialogueBuilder.setView(promptView);

                    final EditText editText = promptView.findViewById(R.id.edittable_className);
                    editText.setText((listClasses.get(getAdapterPosition()).getClasses_name()));

                    alertDialogueBuilder.setCancelable(false).setPositiveButton("Update", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                            // long id = classes.get(getAdapterPosition()).getId();

                            String classesBean = editText.getText().toString();

                            try {
                                /**This is as a result of trying to find a solution**/
                                //long classesArraySize = classes.size();
                                // while (classes.get(getAdapterPosition()).getId() < classesArraySize) 

                                /**Source of error**/
                                ((ClassListOnSetup) context).editClassnameAt(classes.get(getAdapterPosition()).getId(), getAdapterPosition(), classesBean);
                            } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException exception){
                                Log.i("Errore", String.valueOf(exception));
                            }
                        }
                    }).setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                            dialogInterface.cancel();
                        }
                    });

                    AlertDialog alert = alertDialogueBuilder.create();
                    alert.show();
                }
            });
        }
    }

    public ClassListOnSetupRecyclerAdapter(Context context, List<ClassesBean> classes){

        mContext = context;
        listClasses = classes;
    }

    @Override
    public ClassListOnSetupRecyclerAdapter.ClassListOnSetupViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.item_classesname_recycler,parent,false);

        return new ClassListOnSetupViewHolder(mContext,itemView,listClasses);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ClassListOnSetupViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        holder.textView_classname.setText(listClasses.get(position).getClasses_name());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        Log.v(ClassListOnSetupRecyclerAdapter.class.getSimpleName(),"ListClasses"+listClasses.size());
        return listClasses.size();
    }
}
```

And my JavaBean Class called ClassesBean

```
public class ClassesBean {

    private Long id;
    private int classes_item_index;
    private String classes_name;
    private String classes_codename;
    private String classes_sections;
    private String classes_teachers;
    private String classes_students;

    public int getClasses_item_index() {

        return classes_item_index;
    }

    public void setClasses_item_index(int classes_item_index) {
        this.classes_item_index = classes_item_index;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getClasses_name() {

        return classes_name;
    }

    public void setClasses_name(String classes_name) {
        this.classes_name = classes_name;
    }

    public String getClasses_codename() {
        return classes_codename;
    }

    public void setClasses_codename(String classes_codename) {
        this.classes_codename = classes_codename;
    }

    public String getClasses_sections() {
        return classes_sections;
    }

    public void setClasses_sections(String classes_sections) {
        this.classes_sections = classes_sections;
    }

    public String getClasses_teachers() {
        return classes_teachers;
    }

    public void setClasses_teachers(String classes_teachers) {
        this.classes_teachers = classes_teachers;
    }

    public String getClasses_students() {
        return classes_students;
    }

    public void setClasses_students(String classes_students) {
        this.classes_students = classes_students;
    }



}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*My original answer stated that you should add the listeners in `onBindViewHolder()`. This worked but it was not the most optimal solution, as new listener objects are created every time `onBindViewHolder()` is called.*

Adding the listeners in the constructor is correct, however, `getAdapterPosition()` can [sometimes](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.ViewHolder#getAdapterPosition()) return -1 (`RecyclerView.NO_POSITION`).

The solution is to check if `getAdapterPosition() == RecyclerView.NO_POSITION` and ignore the call if it's true.

```
 public ClassListOnSetupViewHolder(final Context context, View itemView, final List<ClassesBean> classes) {

    super(itemView);

    delete_button_classsetup = itemView.findViewById(R.id.delete_button_classsetup);

    delete_button_classsetup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            int adapterPosition = getAdapterPosition();
            if (adapterPosition == RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                return;
            }

            Log.i("Deletes", "Button pressed");
            long id = classes.get(adapterPosition).getId();

            ((ClassListOnSetup) context).removeAt(adapterPosition, classes.get(adapterPosition).getId());
            Toast.makeText(context, "You Clicked ID = " + id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    // ...
 }
```

Comment: Hello @MinasMina, the class ClasslistOnsetup is used to call it's method "editclassnameat()". This class contains all decleard variables like,  database, recycle view, view manger etc. And it works perfectly fine. My problem lies withing the getAdapterPosition method

Comment: also Your suggestion not to pass `List<ClassesBean> classes` does not provide the solution to my problem. @MinasMina

Comment: @Aham_Uzoma I know, I was just pointing it out. I will look at your question again later and see if I find something :)

Comment: Thank you very much @MinasMina your time is very much appriciated!

Comment: Please try the following: Attach the listeners in `onBindViewHolder()` instead of the constructor of the view holder. Use `position` supplied by the method instead of calling `getAdapterPosition()`.

Comment: I arrived at this stage in the development as a result of numerous errors while using just `position` and some other code conflicts is there no other way around this?@MinasMina

Comment: @Aham_Uzoma I'd say no. `onBindViewHolder()` is the place for this stuff. You first need to move the code I mentioned above and then slowly figure out other bugs that might arise. :)

Comment: ok where then does the present code in the `onBindViewHolder()` go @MinasMina

Comment: @Aham_Uzoma You mean `holder.textView_classname.setText()`? It stays there.

Comment: Does `ClassListOnSetupViewHolder` remain empty? @MinasMina , What should it contain if it doesn't remain empty?

Comment: @Aham_Uzoma It should contain the initialization of the vies: `super(itemView); textView_classname = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView_classname); delete_button_classsetup = itemView.findViewById(R.id.delete_button_classsetup);`

Comment: Hello @MinasMina after 3 days of struggling to fix this issue, your suggestion was finally the right and suitable one though `super(itemView); textView_classname = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView_classname); delete_button_classsetup = itemView.findViewById(R.id.delete_button_classsetup);` was still defined in the `ViewHolder` but the rest of the code was moved to the `onBindViewHolder` method I am very grateful. It worked Like Magic!!!. Update your answer to this present suggestion so I could mark it as the right answer.

Comment: @Aham_Uzoma I'm glad that you found it! I have updated the answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

getAdapterPosition() return -1.It means Adapter gets a NO_POSITION,and it always happened when you call notifyDataSetChanged().so,you can edit the log of getAdapterPosition().At the same time,you should make sure getAdapterPosition() != -1 or getAdapterPosition() whthin  the index of list before you call list.get(index).By the way,we always set click listener in the onBindViewHolder() rather than the constructor of ViewHolder.

Comment: Hello @TangXianQiang Thanks for the answer can your give me code samples to illustrate more on ur answer, I am finding it difficult to grab. Am still android amarture.